# Newmarket Delphi - CSV Creation to export data

Tags: csv

Version of Newmarket Delphi I'm using:

[image]

I am looking for help with creating a CSV from all of the data (Contacts, Bookings) that is available inside of my old Delphi, because I would like to be able to just import the data into our newer Salesforce backed Delphi system without having to input every single booking manually into the Salesforce interface.

Is there a way to do this, or am I just stuck inputting everything by hand?

The input interface on the new system:

[image]

Comment: What kind of "Delphi" is that? The Delphi tag you put this Q in is about [a completely different thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delphi_(software)).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand looks like Newmarket Delphi is a hotel hospitality sales & catering system: https://www.hospitalitynet.org/news/4061882.html.

Comment: This is not the Delphi corresponding to the tag "Delphi" (Embarcadero Delphi, a programming environment).